# How to properly unpack data from PHP array encoded as JSON from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, chart.js

I have been doing searches for hours upon hours and have tried different snippets of codes and techniques and I simply cannot get any of them to work. I have done research, I am simply a very inexperienced developer trying to learn as I go.

**My ultimate goal:** Have a live-updating graph of test results data pulled from a MySQL database and rendered using Chart.JS library.

**What I have done so far:**

1. I have an HTML file with embedded JavaScript and calls to AJAX function to auto-refresh page every 5 minutes (this has been tested and works).
2. I have a PHP file which opens a PDO connection to a local MySQL database, runs 3 selection queries, and stores the results into 3 PHP arrays. (I have iterated through the arrays and echoed the results and the data is good).
3. I have then stored the data inside these PHP arrays into a JSON object using **json_encode()** 
   e.g. 
   `$totalTestsPassedArray = array();
   $sql = "SELECT totalTestsPassed FROM execution ORDER BY lastDate";
   $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute(array(':totalTestsPassed' => $totalTestsPassed));
   while($row = $query->fetch()){
       array_push($totalTestsPassedArray, $row['totalTestsPassed']);
   }
   $json_totalTestsPassedArray = json_encode($totalTestsPassedArray); //pack data into JSON object
   echo $json_totalTestsPassedArray; // for accessibility by AJAX
   foreach ($totalTestsPassedArray as $item){ //print out contents of array
       echo $item . '<br>';
   }`

I read that one method to consume this JSON data is to use jQuery's $.getJSON method, and in order to use it, I must 'echo' out the results of my json_encoded object. I realize I am printing the results twice. The **echo $json_totalTestsPassedArray** is for the aforementioned purpose.

4. I have included the path of this PHP file in my HTML file from #1 using `<?php require '../file_name.php';?>`
5. I have tried several ways of unpacking this JSON encoded object packed with my database data: using AJAX requests, making a new array in the HTML and then flooding it with the JSON object using $.getJSON, and some other things people have suggested to do on various documents online, all met with failure.

Could someone please tell me the proper way to do what I am trying to do? **I have a PHP file with an array of data, and I would like to pass that array of data into a dataset for use by Chart.JS** to populate a graph and then draw it to the canvas and display my results.

```
var data = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [DATA FROM MY PHP ARRAY IN ANOTHER FILE WOULD GO HERE...]
            }
```

Again, please forgive my ignorance. I have tried my best to figure out the solution on my own and would really appreciate some guidance. It's my first time using these tools. I thought it would be as simple as:

- Query DB using PHP script
- Store results into array
- Pack into JSON object (the goal being to transfer data from PHP to JS file)
- Unpack JSON object in JavaScript
- Load unpacked data into my JavaScript array

Comment: I think you're not far from the solution, just consider two things: 1. an `ajax` and an `$.getJSON` expect to receive only ONE json-object. 2. $.getJSON does not do much more than the ajax, but receives json only (were as ajax can consume basicly everything like xml, html,..)

Comment: so please get rid of the `foreach` and post any errors you get (in your console (F12))!

Comment: When you call your script, be sure that you ONLY have a json displayed, else it's no longer json and javascript won't understand it ;-)
So no debug message, nothing, just json!

Comment: @Jeff, I get no errors on the console when I remove the foreach, I get the json encoded object containing the values I would expect ["99","66","65","65","65","60",null,null,"40",etc....]
So if $.getJSON only expects one JSON object, but I want to fetch the contents of 3 php arrays in my JS file to populate my graph, is there another method I should be using? And what is the proper way, in my html, to receive that data from my php file?

Comment: if you want to receive 3 different jsons from 3 different php-scripts you will need to have 3 different ajax calls. Or you make your php include all 3 data-sets in one json like ` {"set1": [{obj1}, {obj2}. ...], "set2": {"something different":1}, "set3": [ ..any other array..] } `

Answer (score 0):

In php print only `json` and set header `content type` to `application/json` then your `XHR` response will contain javascript object with your data. There is no need for any json parsing.

Comment: So I removed all my other echo statements except for the one printing the json_encoded object, and set the content-type to be application/json. Running the script now only displays the json object containing the data that I want, but what would be the next step to consume that data in my html file?

Comment: in your ajax, you get that json as response in the callback `.then(response) {...}`. inside that you can consume it like that: `var myData = JSON.parse(response);`